# MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator fails unexpectadly

Tags: airflow

I have the following code:

```
file_name = gcs_export_uri_template + '/' + TABLE_PREFIX + '_' + TABLE_NAME + '{}.json'  #{} is required for the operator. if file is big it breakes it to more files as 1.json 2.json etc
import_orders_op = MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator(
    task_id='import_orders',
    mysql_conn_id='sqlcon',
    google_cloud_storage_conn_id='gcpcon',
    provide_context=True,
    sql=""" SELECT * FROM {{ params.table_name }} WHERE orders_id > {{ params.last_imported_id }} AND orders_id < {{ ti.xcom_pull('get_max_order_id') }} limit 10 """,
    params={'last_imported_id': LAST_IMPORTED_ORDER_ID, 'table_name' :  TABLE_NAME},
    bucket=GCS_BUCKET_ID,
    filename=file_name,
    dag=dag)
```

This works well. However notice that the query have `limit 10` 
When I remove it as:

```
sql=""" SELECT * FROM {{ params.table_name }} WHERE orders_id > {{ params.last_imported_id }} AND orders_id < {{ ti.xcom_pull('get_max_order_id') }} """,
```

It fails with:

```
[2018-10-08 09:09:38,830] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: Traceback (most recent call last):
[2018-10-08 09:09:38,830] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 27, in <module>
[2018-10-08 09:09:38,830] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:     args.func(args)
[2018-10-08 09:09:38,830] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 392, in run
[2018-10-08 09:09:38,830] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:     pool=args.pool,
[2018-10-08 09:09:38,830] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 50, in wrapper
[2018-10-08 09:09:38,831] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:     result = func(*args, **kwargs)
[2018-10-08 09:09:38,831] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/models.py", line 1493, in _run_raw_task
[2018-10-08 09:09:38,831] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:     result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
[2018-10-08 09:09:38,831] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/mysql_to_gcs.py", line 89, in execute
[2018-10-08 09:09:38,831] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:     files_to_upload = self._write_local_data_files(cursor)
[2018-10-08 09:09:38,831] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/mysql_to_gcs.py", line 134, in _write_local_data_files
[2018-10-08 09:09:38,832] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:     json.dump(row_dict, tmp_file_handle)
[2018-10-08 09:09:38,832] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 189, in dump
[2018-10-08 09:09:38,832] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:     for chunk in iterable:
[2018-10-08 09:09:38,832] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 434, in _iterencode
[2018-10-08 09:09:38,832] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:     for chunk in _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level):
[2018-10-08 09:09:38,832] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 390, in _iterencode_dict
[2018-10-08 09:09:38,832] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:     yield _encoder(value)
[2018-10-08 09:09:38,833] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 5: invalid start byte
```

I can only assume that the reason is the file_name with the `{}.json` maybe if it has too many records and it needs to split the file it can't?

I'm running Airflow 1.9.0

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your limit 10 just happens to be returning a clean 10 rows of unambiguous ASCII encoding. However, your larger select is returning something that is not decoding with UTF-8. I had this when my MySQL Connection has no extras set.

If you have no extras at all, edit your connection to have `{"charset": "utf8"}` in the extras field. If you have extras, just add that key-value pair into the collection.

This should establish an encoding for the MySQL client the hook uses to retrieve records, and things should start decoding correctly. Whether or not they'll write to GCS is an exercise left to you.

Comment: What is extra exactly? The table defined as:  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

Comment: It's something that provides flexible kwargs to hooks that load connections, or just notes to self… The MySQLHook specifically says you can throw in "charset" and it does a couple of things actually, one is set a flag to use unicode. I had the mysql db set to use utf-8 but that didn't mean the hook was decoding utf-8 correctly till I set this.
https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/hooks/mysql_hook.py#L30
Not really shown in the docs though: https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/howto/manage-connections.html